# Ajax on textfield keeps me from typing

Tags: 7, ajax

I have the ajax property set on a form element.  Its like an autocomplete except it displays the results in a div.  It works great except the textfield gets greyed out by drupal during the ajax call.  I end up having to type one character at a time between ajax calls.  Is there a way to fix this?

Here's the code for my element:

```
$form['auto_complete'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Auto Complete',
  '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'k_test_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'searchresults',
      'method' => 'html',
      'event' => 'keyup',
    ),
 );
```

Comment: It looks like this is the default behavior for drupal... is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to either

- use the `#autocomplete_path` and tweak the behavior by overriding the JavaScript (prototyping)
- Don't use the ajax framework, but create this with custom JavaScript.

The AJAX framework can do a lot of things for you, and works very great for most things, but there are some cases like this one, where it doesn't work as intended. The problem is that you will get too many ajax requests at once if you do one for every `keyup` event, which most likely will mess things up if you could actually do it. This is why you need an autocomplete functionality which usually caches the results for improved performance.